# How to transfer object via data binding to parent componen - Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-component

In my Vuejs application I have a select element, where the user can select a country. A country element looks like:

```
country {  
  id: 1,  
  name: 'Germany',  
  sort: 1 
}
```

I get a list of these country objects from my database (called countries) and load them into my select:

```
<select 
  id="countrySelect" 
  :value="country" 
  @change="$emit('update:country', $event.target.value);"> 
  <option selected disabled>Choose...</option> 
  <option v-for="data in countries" :value="data" :key="data">{{ data.name }}</option> 
</select>

props: {   country: Object }

emits: ['update:country']
```

Now in my parent component I implement this component and want to set the country object in my store to the selected object when the selection of the country changes.

```
<countryComponent :country=store.requestObject.country @update:country="changeCountry" />
```

Now in my method changeCountry, I try to set the value in the store to the selected country object like:

```
changeCountry(value) { 
 console.log(value) //returns [Object object] 
 this.store.requestObject.country = value; 
}
```

Because of certain reasons i am not able to use v-model directly. My main problem is that the value in my method is always [Object object] and not the real object itself. Also in my store the value of store.requestObject.country is "[Object object]". Isn't it possible to transfer objects via this kind of binding or am I doing something wrong?

My store object looks like:

```
requestObject: {
 country:Object,
 ...
}
```

Comment: <select>is unaware of objects and stringifies country object to "[Object object]". so are <option>. You need to deal with country ids and associate them with respective objects yourself

Comment: @EstusFlask okay, yeah i think i have to work with the id's then. thanks for your explanation either! :)

Comment: HTML tags never accept non-string values